# How to auto log in with Github access code?

Tags: git, github

My account is 2FA enabled. Github [asks](https://github.blog/2013-09-03-two-factor-authentication/#how-does-it-work-for-command-line-git) to use an access code instead of the password for logging in. Is there anyway to store it on my remote machine so that I do not have to mention again and again?

Comment: You can't store a 2FA, it changes constantly, that's the point.

Comment: @Liam did you understand the question? where did I mention that 2Fa value is being accessed or stored? And is this you who downvoted and asked for the close? Yes, please undo it.

Comment: I don't understand. Your link shows a picture where you are asked to check your app for the access token. In English, your sentence is asking to store this access token somewhere on the remote machine. Then you use "mention again and again", which is confusing. Mention doesn't mean input, so maybe we are loosing a lot in translation?

Comment: @DaemonPainter it means when I run `git clone` on CLI it asks password which is not my github password but access token which is very long

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm that you are not using ssh for clone?
If so, please check if [this link](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent) help

Comment: Yes I am not using SSH,  am using HTTP one.